# Copying a Range from Excel and Pasting it into Powerpoint NOT as a metafile but as a table which you can edit in PPP

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

All I want to do is copy a range from Excel and then paste this range into PowerPoint.

When my range is manually copied from Excel to the clipboard... If I right click on a blank slide when pasting into PowerPoint, it gives me the option to paste "using destination styles".

This means that I can edit the resulting table. This is the result I want.

So far I have only found solutions which involve pasting in as a metafile.

If you have a solution please can you show me the full code including the dimensions as VBA in PowerPoint really isn't my cup of tea.

Thanks in advance for restoring my sanity!

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

        Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
        Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
        Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject


     'Look for existing instance
        On Error Resume Next
        Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0



    'Show the PowerPoint
        newPowerPoint.Visible = True


            newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.count
            Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.count)


            ActiveSheet.Range("d51:d57").Copy
            activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
            newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 165
            newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 395

    AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")

    Set activeSlide = Nothing
    Set newPowerPoint = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI This site is for asking for help not for asking someone to write all of your code for you. I see you already have one downvote and I bet more are coming unless you edit your post to include the code that you've already written. In other words, you need to demonstrate that you've really tried to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: Agree with Rachel. Also, your question is not very clear. Do you mean that you have found a manual solution pasting "using destination styles", but you want to know how to do this in VBA code?

Comment: If you meant manual copy-and-paste: you can achieve editable table by inserting a table in PowerPoint *before* pasting the data from Excel into said table.

Comment: Sorry all - haven't posted before! Code is shown above. I can paste as an enhanced metafile (a picture) but cant paste as a table as you would be able to do manually if you right clicked and selected "Keep source formatting" or "Use destination Styles"

Comment: See this SO post: [paste-excel-range-into-powerpoint-as-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782220/paste-excel-range-into-powerpoint-as-table)

Comment: Hi Rachel... No that didn't work because it pasted it as an enhanced metafile. I need to  paste it as a table which I can edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be no corresponding method in the PowerPoint object model. The only way to do this is to call the ribbon button itself:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("d51:d57").Copy
newPowerPoint.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting")
```

BTW: To find the list of ribbon buttons, search for "Office 2010 Control IDs".

Comment: Rachel Hettinger... Hero!   Many Thanks